# If statement making pygame sprite invisible

Tags: pygame, sprite

I am making a very simple game that has coins on a surface, a player that is a black block (for now) and a computer AI that is, for now, a penguin. Last night I got everything I implemented to work. I say implemented because I haven't even started implementing an endgame scenario/condition. I was so happy last night that I got the AI to work.... too good. In this small paradigm it is impossible to win. I decided to take away the AI's ability to make diagonal turns. I did this by making a single if statement into an elif:

```
# Uncomment if you want the AI to be able to go diagonal
'''def hunt(self, player_xy):
    if player_xy[0] > self.get_x():
        self.set_x(self.get_x() + 3)
    elif player_xy[0] < self.get_x():
        self.set_x(self.get_x() - 3)

    if player_xy[1] > self.get_y():
        self.set_y(self.get_y() + 3)
    elif player_xy[1] < self.get_y():
        self.set_y(self.get_y() - 3) '''

def hunt(self, player_xy):
    if player_xy[0] > self.get_x():
        self.set_x(self.get_x() + 3)
    elif player_xy[0] < self.get_x():
        self.set_x(self.get_x() - 3)
    elif player_xy[1] > self.get_y():
        self.set_y(self.get_y() + 3)
    elif player_xy[1] < self.get_y():
        self.set_y(self.get_y() - 3)
```

I have a label on the background that tells me where the AI is, so I can track it. When the if statement is still an if statement, I can see the label move and I can see the sprite move. When I change the one line to an elif, I still see the label move (therefore the sprite is moving) but I don't see the sprite anywhere. Seriously, 1 line.

Any thoughts on why this is happening or what I should do about it? I can post more of my code, but since I have it isolated to 1 line, I didn't think it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I am dumb.

The sprite isn't invisible, it just loads off the screen and it takes a long time to be able to see it because it can no longer move diagonal. It moves laterally until it is in line with me then it moves vertically. Makes sense.